# JavaMail from OpenShift: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: gmail, java-8, openshift, jakarta-mail

I have an application deployed on OpenShift, from which I need to send email to and from a single Google account.

With the application deployed locally, it works perfectly; however, when trying the same with the application deployed on OpenShift, I get the following authorisation error:

> 19:23:16,265 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 wn10sm1673177wjc.46 - gsmtp
>
> 19:23:16,266 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:843)

Everything else works perfectly in my OpenShift deployment.

This is what my implementation looks like:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", myEmail);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myEmail));
        InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(myEmail);
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

        message.setSubject(title);
        message.setText(msg);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, myEmail, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
    catch (AddressException ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have tried the following solutions proposed in the URL from the exception trace and as answers to other SO questions:

- Allowed less secure apps is ON in Google settings
- Tried with both **user@gmail.com** and **user** for the sender
- Allowed access to the Google account from https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
- The 2-step verification is OFF in Google settings
- Waited >10 minutes between tries, to allow for some "cool-off" between unsuccessful authorisations

Comment: Gmail can be very picky about which IP addresses it allows to connect.  Perhaps a previous user of your OpenShift IP address was abusing Gmail?  You might need to use an app password with Gmail, or perhaps use [OAuth2 authentication](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) to get around this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! In the meantime, I circumvented the problem by setting up a cron job that uses the mail command. The mails are sent without any issues.