# mail not going using gmail smtp laravel and cakephp

Tags: php, email, cakephp

At first, emails were sending but both in cakephp and laravel project, emails stopped going. Now, i am getting error:

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8
>   Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 xn11sm52558396pac.38 -
>   gsmtp"

I had removed 2 step verification, turned on the toggle button of allowing access to less secure apps, also unlocked captcha etc. I had tried every step that I found on google.

```
public $smtp = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'message@abc.com',
        'password' => '123',
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('noreply@abc.com' => 'abc'),
        'timeout' => 10,
        'client' => null,
        'log' => true,
        'ssl' => true,
        'sender' => array('noreply@abc.com')
    );
```

I had put here the dummy credentials

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */
    'from' => ['address' => 'noreply@abc.com', 'name' => 'abc'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'ssl',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'message@abc.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'test'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

];
```

Comment: Would you provide the code and configuration you are using?

Comment: Please add the mail.php file configuration.

Comment: @MinaAbadir, which file you are talking about. Please let me know. I am a newbie in cakephp

Comment: Why are you tagging your question for Laravel, while you are using CakePHP?

Comment: I am using the code both in cakephp and laravel.. laravel has also the same credentials which i updated above. Give me a minute. I will update them also @MinaAbadir

Comment: My recommendation was for Laravel configuration

Comment: @MinaAbadir, i had updated my question with laravel mail.php file

Comment: I do really love to support, but which framework are you using? Are you choosing between both?

Comment: @MinaAbadir, I have a project which is made in cakephp and for the app, laravel is used for web services. Mail is not going in both the frameworks.

Comment: Do you have SSL support for PHP?

Comment: @MinaAbadir , Yes, I have. Everything was working fine.. mail just stopped 2 days back

Comment: @MinaAbadir, i username and password fields, do i need to pass the gmail credentials or anything else?

Comment: Yes Gmail credentials

Comment: @Ku Hye Sun Had the same problem when trying to email (with GMail account) from application deployed on OpenShift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884451/javamail-from-openshift-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-8-use Could be that GMail is blocking you somehow.

Comment: @MinaAbadir, the above sma econfiguration now works in cakephp, not in laravel.. Can you let me know where mail configuration settings are done in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

here you might have some usefull tips:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/QTaNoX4QABk

Comment: I had tried everything.. I had changed my account password but i also replaced that password in my code. @adeptofvoltron